# Coffee vending machine simulation with testbench issue

Tags: verilog, fsm, test-bench

I have written Verilog code for a simple coffee vending machine with     inputs

> 25ps,50ps,75ps and 1

as

> "00","01","10" and "11"

respectively. Coffee cost is 1 rs. If more than 1 rs is inserted, the balance will be returned. That balance will be

> 01, 10, 11

as

> 25ps, 50ps, 1rs

respectively. I simulate this without testbench. The simulation takes double clock pulse for output.  When I put 25 ps 8 times or 8 clock pulses is required for getting output. The expected clock pulse is 4. Why does this happen?

Also, I didn't get output when using the testbench.
Is the clock frequency divider necessary while doing the programme in an FPGA board to see output? It is working as expected when I programmed into fpga board.  I'm using Xilinx vivado 2015.2 tool and zynq board.

```
//programme
module main(
input clk,
input rst,
input [1:0] money,
output coffee,
output [1:0] balance
);    
             
reg coff;
reg  [1:0] bal;
reg  [2:0] pr_st;
reg  [2:0] nx_st;
parameter [2:0] A=3'b000;
parameter [2:0] B=3'b001;
parameter [2:0] C=3'b010;
parameter [2:0] D=3'b011;
parameter [2:0] E=3'b100;
parameter [2:0] F=3'b101;
parameter [2:0] G=3'b110;
parameter [2:0] H=3'b111;

always @ (posedge clk or posedge rst)
begin
if(rst)
pr_st <= A;
else 
pr_st <= nx_st;
end

always @(posedge clk)         
begin
case(pr_st)
A : if(money == 2'b00) // input money is 25ps
begin
nx_st <= B; 
end
else if(money == 2'b01)  // input money is 50ps
begin
nx_st <= C;                       
end
else if(money == 2'b10)  // input money is 75ps
begin
nx_st <= D;                        
end
else if(money == 2'b11)
begin
nx_st <= E;                   
end
B : if(money == 2'b00)    
begin
nx_st <= C;                         
end 
else if(money == 2'b01) 
begin
nx_st <= D; 
end
else if(money == 2'b10)
begin
nx_st <= E;                       
end  
else if(money == 2'b11)
begin 
nx_st <= F;                        
end  
C : if(money == 2'b00)         
begin
nx_st <= D;                      
end 
else if(money == 2'b01)
begin 
nx_st <= E;                        
end 
else if(money == 2'b10)
begin 
nx_st <= F;                      
end
else if(money == 2'b11)
begin  
nx_st <= G;                      
end       
D : if(money == 2'b00)
begin           
nx_st <= E;                          
end
else if(money == 2'b01)  
begin
nx_st <= F;                        
end
else if(money == 2'b10)  
begin
nx_st <= G; 
end
else if(money == 2'b11)
begin
nx_st <= H;                      
end
E :   nx_st <= A;
F :   nx_st <= A;
G :   nx_st <= A;
H :   nx_st <= A;
default : nx_st <= A;           
endcase
end 
//output logic
always @( posedge clk or pr_st)
begin
case(pr_st)
A: begin
coff <= 1'b0;
bal <= 2'b00; 
end 
B: begin
coff <= 1'b0;
bal <= 2'b00; 
end 
C: begin
coff <= 1'b0;
bal <= 2'b00; 
end 
D: begin
coff <= 1'b0; 
bal <= 2'b00; 
end 
E: begin
coff <= 1'b1;
bal<= 2'b00;        
end
F: begin
coff <= 1'b1;
bal <= 2'b01;       
end
G: begin
coff <= 1'b1;
bal <= 2'b10;
end
H: begin 
coff <= 1'b1;
bal <= 2'b11;       
end
default : begin
off <=1'b0;
bal <= 2'b00;
end  
endcase                       
end 

assign coffee = coff;
assign balance = bal;

endmodule

//test bench
module tb_main(
);
reg clk;
reg rst;
reg [1:0] money;
wire coffee;
wire [1:0] balance;

main dut( clk, rst, money, coffee, balance);
always
begin
#200 clock = ~clk; 
end 

initial
begin
rst = 1'b1;
#100 rst = 1'b0;
money = 2'b00; // putting 25ps four times to get coffee
#400 money = 2'b01; //putting 50ps two times to get coffee
#200 money = 2'b10;// putting 75ps two times to get coffee
#200 money = 2'b11;// putting 1 rs single time to g
#100 money = 2'b01; // putting 1st 25ps and  50ps i n second clock cycle
#100 money = 2'b10;
#200
$finish
end 
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your clock signal to a known value in the testbench.  You should speed up the clock because your `money` input changes faster than the clock:

```
initial clk = 0;
always begin
    #10 clk = ~clk; 
end
```

Also, you mistakenly used a signal named `clock` in the testbench when it should have been `clk`.